# ADF Skin build ignores SVG images

Tags: build, oracle-adf, skinning

I am currently developing a `Skin` for a `ADF Fusion Web Application` using both, the `JDeveloper 11.1.2.0` and the `Skin Editor 11.1.2.0`.

For some `background-image` rules I use `SVG` images. However these `SVG` images are not copied to the right folder in my `lookAndFeel.jar` during deployment. All my `PNG` images are copied to in following maner

```
lookAndFeel.jar\META-INF\adf\skins\<skinname>\images\*.png
```

where my `SVG` images are left behind in

```
lookAndFeel.jar\skins\<skinname>\images\*.svg
```

I was able to work around this issue with the following command, leveraging `7zip`:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a lookAndFeel.jar META-INF\adf\skins\<skinname>\images\*.svg
```

That adds those `SVG` images post deploy into the right folder of my `JAR` file.

However this is not very elegant, and I wonder if there is a better solution, which I can adopt later in the automatic build job. Is there a way to configure the skin build, to include the `SVG` images? Or is it extensible with an `Ant` file? If so, could somebody direct me into the right direction, as I never used `Ant` myself before?

edit

Both my `PNG` and `SVG` images are in the same folder, so the Source-path seems to be right. And I found the following section in my Project File:

```
<hash n="oracle.jdeveloper.compiler.OjcConfiguration">
    <list n="copyRes">
        <string v=".cpx"/>
        <string v=".dcx"/>
        <string v=".ejx"/>
        <string v=".gif"/>
        <string v=".ini"/>
        <string v=".jpeg"/>
        <string v=".jpg"/>
        <string v=".png"/>
        <string v=".properties"/>
        <string v=".sva"/>
        <string v=".svg"/>
        <string v=".tag"/>
        <string v=".tld"/>
        <string v=".wsdl"/>
        <string v=".xcfg"/>
        <string v=".xlf"/>
        <string v=".xml"/>
        <string v=".xsd"/>
        <string v=".xsl"/>
    </list>
```

There are both `PNG` and `SVG` listed. I did not found another place where `PNG` was in my Project File.

Answer (score 0):

This file might be excluded from the project's deployment

There are two things to check:

1. Make sure that the Project's Source Paths includes all
2. Edit your deployment profile, and make sure you include any files from filter under your images folder, or even add the rule *.svg yourself rule if not there